# How to update clients which access a windows service on a remote server?

Tags: .net, windows-services, desktop-application

Update involves updating the binary and quite a few libraries. Please advise if this is possible by tweaking just the server side? Maybe, if I could just send a message with a link for the updates. Currently, There is no provision

It uses a tcp channel configuration to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but if it's not built-in to the application already you'll need to add it.

IMO, the fastest way to do so would be to switch your client application over to a click-once deployment scheme (if this is a .NET 3.0 or later WinForms/WPF application). There may be some security ramifications if it's not built/configured/deployed in just the right manner though.

Comment: The app is built on .Net 2.0
As much as I would love to update the client side with as many features necessary I have to stick to the server side code for the time being as the update would have the features as desired. By tweaking only server side, I dont have to mail all the users about the update, those who use the old version will be shown a message about a pending update and they would migrate on their own

Comment: For the client side to update, the client has to do something (either the user has to do it manually, or the client, acting as the user does it automatically).  Just making changes to the server code will have no effect on the client if the client doesn't know what to do with the msgs it receives. .NET 2.0 does have a mechanism by which this can be coded in the Updater Enterprise Application Block (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978574.aspx), but you will still have to get the user to install the next version manually, but then going forward updates would happen automagically.